# How to remove NUL bytes from text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

My output file is creating NUL bytes(\x00) for every line.I am running python 2.7 on Unix and  file will be  processed on Windows later

```
with open(inputfile,'w') as f:
           f.write(cmd_output)


command_process = subprocess.Popen(
cmd,
shell=shl,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
universal_newlines=True
)


 cmd_output = command_process.communicate()[0]
```